# How to reset view each time its closed?

Tags: iphone, view

I have a table view that displays contact information. I have another view that acts as a "contact pad." Basically it has either empty or text filled rows. I want it to have empty rows (or default state) when the user taps on a button on the tableview and I want it to pre-populate text when the user taps a row on the tableview. My methods for writing/reading to the datasource work fine, but once the "contact pad" view is brought up; it saves its state.

For example, if I open the "contact pad" view with the button then it shows the proper default state. Then if I open the "contact pad" view via tapping on a row it will display the correct text, but if I go try to open it again via the button then it will not re-show the default state and instead will show the text from before.

How do I reset a view once it has been closed? Do I call dealloc() before [self removeFromSuperview]?

Answer (score 0):

In the `viewWillAppear` method, just do a

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

This method will be called every time there is  a navigation or each time the view is opened.

Comment: reloadData does not know which state to do though. I change states by using if's during cellForRowAtIndexPath:, but the problem is that the variable I am testing for does not get reset after the view is closed. I set its value in the init and viewDidLoad methods, but these methods are not called after the view has been loaded once. I need to throw it out of memory programmatically. How can I achieve that?

Comment: lol. The problem you are facing is not with the code. It's just needs a good logical layout. I would simply use `NSUserDefaults` to communicate between views and check for changes in the previous screen and based on that I act in the `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @crzrcn you can try resetting the variable's value in viewWillDisAppear method.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that after you add your view as a subview its retain count goes up by 1.
So if you remove it from the superview it comes down by 1. You should release your subview after you add it to another view. This way when you call removeFromSuperview it counts get down by one and gets freed totally.